# How to extract an Id from URL in angular e2e testing

Tags: angularjs, e2e-testing

I am writing e2e test cases for my angular application using protractor.
Here is my code

```
it('Select Dashboard.....', function(){ 
             element.all(by.css('.caption p a')).get(0).click();
             browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function(url) {
               expect(url.split('#')[1]).toBe('/patientDashboard/encounters/1');
             });
         });
```

How to extract ID from the URL(/patientDashboard/encounters/1)?
Because I am using the same URL in multiple places with different ID.

Comment: `/\d+$/.exec(url)[0]`

Comment: @Phil Can you please explain clearly